# Two "who"s in a sentence

Tags: grammar

I want to know whether this sentence is grammarly correct or not:

> As a person who is 50 years old and who has been working in this field for 27 years, he is an expert for sure.

I was thinking should it be:

> As a person who is 50 years old and has been working in this field for 27 years, he is an expert for sure.

The sentence I want to write has the same structure as the first sentence. Is it correct to use two "who"s like that?

I know I can place the "50 years old" in front of the "person", but I am interested in knowing whether this kind of structure works.

Comment: Why do you think it might not be? Is there a rule you've been told about?

Comment: @JohnLawler I was thinking if it should be: As a person who is 50 years old and has been working in this field for 27 years, he is an expert for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both sentences are correct.  In the second sentence, without the second “who”, the assumption is that the first who still applies.

Some might feel that the (unnecessary) relative pronoun is just a little clearer.  But it is a matter of individual preference.